# How to get <input> default value in this code?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

In my javascript code, I want to retrieve  the value of a TAG placed in page_1 (which id is: "token"), i've tried the following but it does not work:

```
<iframe id="Myiframe" src="http://page_1">

<script>
   doc = document.getElementById('Myiframe');   
   value = doc.getElementById("token").value;
</script>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Try `doc.contentWindow.document.getElementById('token').value`

Comment: You're iframe need to be in the same domain as your page because of Same Origin Policy.

Comment: Is there a way to bypass this Origin Policy ?

Comment: The only way is to use server side proxy script that's on the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("myText").defaultValue
```